# Error while uploading mapping.txt file to parse cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard, crash-reports, parse-cloud-code

I have obfuscated my app using proguard and I have enabled parse crash reporting. In order to see the stack trace in de-obfuscated form I have to upload the mapping.txt to parse's cloud. As I'm using eclipse I can't automate it,so I'm using the manual upload method. I followed the instructions given here https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#crash-reporting-testing
My cloud code directory is set up but when I execute the command

> parse symbols -a path-to-apk path-to-symbols

I get this error

> Uploading symbol files...
>
> Warning: build number is '1'.
>
> Server responded with error.

Tried to debug but no success.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got the same error. Is it a bug?

Comment: I posted this on the parse mailing list, but no replies. Had to eventually go with crashlytics.